# Counting unique numbers in a column MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that returns data in the following format:

```
id | name | number
 1   John    12545
 1   John    50496
 2   Mary    23443
 3   Mark    54
 3   Mark    5600
 3   Mark    50206
```

I would like to find out the number of distinct `ids` that appear in the result set. For example, for the result above. I would like to obtain the value 3.

Is there any way to add a column so the result looks like this instead?

```
count | id | name | number
 3      1   John    12545
 3      1   John    50496
 3      2   Mary    23443
 3      3   Mark    54
 3      3   Mark    5600
 3      3   Mark    50206
```

My query is:

```
 SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id FROM tableA
    WHERE xyz
 ) as t1
 JOIN tableB using (id)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM tableName) totalCount,
       id,name,number
FROM tableName
```

or by using `CROSS JOIN`

```
SELECT x.totalCount,
       a.id, a.name, a.number
FROM tableName a, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) totalCount 
                   FROM tableName) x
```

Comment: Presumably I would have to put the WHERE condition inside the (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT...)) if I wanted to count the number of rows in the table 't1' in my example query?

Comment: you cannot use `WHERE` if the column is aggregated. it should be (*for example*) `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id) > 1`

Comment: I'm slightly confused. Your suggestion implies that I would want to count the rows of a query of an entire table (`.. FROM tableName`)? I only want to count a subset of the rows from the table, chosen using a WHERE clause.

Comment: what do you mean by subset of rows?

Comment: For example, I want to select a bunch of ids where attribute x = 10 from `tableA`. I then want to count the number of ids found and join them with TableB using (id) to get more information like 'name'

Comment: @RogerJarvis [see this link for demonstration](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8510/4) which one of those answers your question?

Comment: Thanks for the SQL fiddle thing, very useful. I've gotten it working now. :)

Comment: so which one of the queries answered your question? :D

Answer (score 0):

You should try :

`SELECT id,name,number, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT name) FROM YourTableName) FROM YourTableName`

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id)` would be faster than using column `name`.

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM tableName) as 'count',
        id,name,number  
FROM tableName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS count , id, name, number 
FROM 
( 
    SELECT id 
    FROM tableA 
    WHERE xyz 
) as t1 
JOIN tableB using (id)
GROUP BY id, name, number
```